# Create SharePoint List programmatically

Tags: list, javascript, rest

I want to create a SharePoint list programmatically from a SP addin.

I would like to know which approach is better:

1. Using JavaScript or
2. Using REST

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 5):

Definitely REST.  SharePoint is moving more into the REST world with each update.  It's how O365 is being geared.  In fact MVP SympMarc (http://sympmarc.com/) who wrote SPServices (for javascript) now has a presentation on how to move from SPServices to REST services.

So definitely go with REST.

Comment: Why is it better than JS? This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: You are correct, I guess it doesn't.  However, when the industry is starting to move away from a technology why not support the technology that will be used more?  He asked which is better.  Right now, both approaches work just fine.  You can create a list using each approach.  But there is strong evidence that shows REST is now the tool to use, in my books that makes it the better approach.  I think this can be quite subjective though.

Comment: Marc is transitioning SPServices from SOAP to REST, it still uses jQuery/Javascript, so I'm not understanding what you are meaning with this.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the JavaScript approach.

The CSOM/Javascript approach gives you much more coverage to the entire SharePoint API than REST. You still need to use Javascript to implement your REST request anyway.

http://www.slideshare.net/mrackley/sharepoint-rest-vs-csom

Comment: I like Eric's answer.  When I was answering mine, I was thinking one of the other.  Which means you would be either writing a Javascript app or another app that called REST services (like a CSOM Mananged code app).  However, as Eric states, with Javascript you actually can have both.

Comment: Thanks for your infos. I tried creating a custom list using REST and what I observed was that I get exactly a list that seems to be created manually using the custom list template and every user could do anything with the list(delete ,add , modify list items and settings etc). And when I delete my app the list remains undeleted! But when I created a custom list using JS the list was actually residing inside my app with almost no option to edit and was deleted when the app was uninstalled. 

In a scenario like this, would you recommend continuing with JS if the data is not important ?